# Get Data Splice from Array in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

here i am trying to get value from my checkbox value and i am trying data in unique type of template cant able to splice it.

Here is my html Code

```
 <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox" *ngFor="let data of Data; let i = index">
            <input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" (click)="SelectedTemplates(check, $event,i)" [checked]="checked" [value]="data.id" id="{{data.appName}}">
              <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{data.appName}}">{{data.templateName}} | {{data.appName}} |
                  {{data.docName}}</label>
          </div>
```

Here is my Typescript Function cant able to get value when i spliced

```
SelectedTemplates(check, event, index) {
if (event.target.checked === true) {
  this.checkedItem = true;
  this.NewArry.push({'partnerId': this.PartnerID, 'templateId': this.Data[index].id});
} else if (event.target.checked === false) {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.NewArry.length; i++) {
    this.checkedItem = false;
    if (this.Data[index].id === this.NewArry[i]) {
      console.log(this.NewArry[i].id);
      this.NewArry.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
}
   this.AreaArr = this.NewArry;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this code in your else if

```
this.NewArry.splice(index, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because of pointers.

Try on `else if`

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.NewArry.length; i++) {
  this.checkedItem = false;
  if (this.Data[index].id !== this.NewArry[i])
    this.AreaArr = [this.NewArry[i], ...this.AreaArr]
}
```

Or

```
this.AreaArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.NewArry))
```